# Chemically, how stains are removed?what is the principal?

Tags: organic-chemistry

How stains are removed? answering to this question will help me much

Comment: I'm afraid this question is too broad. Specifying the type of fabric and source of impurities would help a lot.

Comment: I agree - too broad. However, a general answer is that the appropriate solvent is used for the stain. For example, a nonpolar grease stain is typically removed via a combination of a nonpolar solvent and a surfactant, which "traps" the stain molecule

Comment: Alternatively, substances such as hydrogen peroxide are applied that chemically react with the color compounds in the stain to make them colorless.